# How do I write combined (enumerated) lists in excel via django

Tags: django, excel, list, xlwt

I am trying to create a program using python and django to publish a table of generated primers in an excel spreadsheet. Currently, it successfully creates the workbook with the worksheet but it does not write the primers and the relavent fields into the cells. I am wondering if anyone can give me a hand. I would be really grateful.

Below is part of my relavent code.

```
PrimerA [keys] = filtered primerAList
PrimerB [keys] = filtered_primerBList

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws1 = wb.add_sheet('PrimerA')
ws2 = wb.add_sheet('PrimerB')

iterate_Ct_rownum = 0
iterate_Ga_rownum = 0

for keys in sequence_keylist: #dictionary of all sequennces
    for rownum, sublist in enumerate(PrimerA[keys]):
        ws1.write(iterate_PrimerA_rownum, 0, keys)

    for column, value in enumerate(sublist):
        ws1.write(iterate_PrimerA_rownum, column +1, value)
    iterate_PrimerA_rownum += 1

for rownum, sublist in enumerate(complete_nested_dic_Ga[keys]):
    ws2.write(iterate_PrimerB_rownum, 0, keys)

    for column, value in enumerate(sublist):
        ws2.write(iterate_PrimerB_rownum, column +1, value)
    iterate_PrimerB_rownum += 1


return HttpResponse(open('file.xls','r').read(),
  mimetype='application/ms-excel')
    #return response(open('file.xls','r').read(),
  #mimetype='application/ms-excel')
```

This works fine on the command line but I cannot get it to work in my django app. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: It doesn't display an error. When It doesn't seem to be writing the combined lists into the spreadsheet. I can download the workbook with no problems and it is named 'file.xls' as specified and the sheets are 'primerA' and 'primerB', but both sheets are completely blank. Thanks

Comment: You don't save the Workbook. Try to do a wb.save() before the return.

Comment: I've tried to write a dummy dictionary into a sheet using the following code and it works fine. But for some reason it cannot write my lists into it.  d = {'a':['e1','e2','e3'],'b':['e1','e2'],'c':['e1']} [newline]     for key in d.keys():
        iterate_Ct_rownum += 1
        ws3.write(iterate_Ct_rownum, column,     key)
        for item in d[key]:
            ws3.write(iterate_Ct_rownum, column + 1, item)
            iterate_Ct_rownum += 1